# Autofocus does not work when using the camera button

Tags: lumia, buttons, camera

I have a Nokia Lumia 800.  When I use the camera button to take a photograph, autofocus does not work.  Instead, I tap the subject on the screen for it to focus on it.

I expect to have to tap-to-click when I want to focus on a non-central subject, but why doesn't autofocus work at all when using the dedicated camera button?  What it should do is focus on the central target at least, but it would be better if it had some intelligence to focus on the nearest large object, whether it is in the centre or not, like digital compact cameras usually do.

When using the camera button, as there is no autofocus, it focuses at *infinity*, so it is still useful for landscapes; otherwise, it is only useful to turn on camera mode.

Is this a problem with all Windows Phones, or is it the Nokia camera software?  I understand that the manufacturer is mostly responsible for the camera app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Samsung Focus does autofocus in the center when you press half the dedicated camera button. Some people can't do this because you need to press very soft and see the square on the screen.

This is what you want?

Comment: Hmmn, I really should have thought to try that!

Comment: This is also the case for HTC devices (and most digital cameras)

Answer (score 6):

To autofocus, you need to press tue button half way down. It is sort of difficult, and requires a light touch. The phone should make a noise indicating focus is complete.

Pushing the button the whole way takes the picture as-is, and often the subject will not be in focus. Hope this helps.

Comment: My camera doesn't make a noise. Maybe because I switch off the camera sound.

Answer (score 0):

The autofocus on the lumia 800 doesn't work at all and it's not about how you press the camera button. I've had the lumia 800 myself and am a camera & mobile phone expert. This is a fault that exists in every lumia 800. The autofocus just won't help focus on any foreground object. Only the background. nokia or windows should've just added a working autofocus, or non at all.

The autofocus feature is absolutely useless on the lumia 800.

Comment: Checking some message boards the experience of others differs from yours in regards to the Nokia 800 and auto-focus.

Comment: I remember the auto focus on my 800 to be a bit funny, so I don't disagree with your points but it might help if you can post some other sources. Please also try to follow the site's etiquette http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette